# Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: android

I'm trying to call a service from a activity:

When I'm running the program the activity throws an error which says: Not allowed to start service Intent. What am I doing wrong? I'm sorry for possible stupid mistakes in the code, but I'm a newbie.

activity code:

```
public void startService() {
try { 
startService (new Intent ( this  , SmsReminderService.class)) ; }
catch (Exception e ) { Log.v("Error" , e.getMessage()) }
}
```

service code :

```
public class SmsReminderService extends Service {

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Log.v("SSms", "Service started") ; }}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="me.sms.smsReminder"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<permission android:name="SEND_SMS"></permission>


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SmsReminderActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".SmsReminderService"    
             android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" ></action>
            </intent-filter>

        </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance, Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why this in the service?

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" ></action>
</intent-filter>
```

**Try to add this:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
```